Catboost Installation using cargo rust
I am trying to follow this tutorial which helps serve a catboost model using rust. The installation of the catboost package is proving to be a challenge here.
I have tried doing
cargo install --git "https://github.com/catboost/catboost"

which threw an error saying there are multiple packages namely catboost_rust_prediction_tutorial, catboost-sys and catboost and that I should use
cargo install --git "https://github.com/catboost/catboost" <package_name>

So I installed catboost and catboost-sys using the above command. However when I try to build the rust crate with the tutorial code, I get an error
error: failed to run custom build command for `catboost-sys v0.1.0 (https://github.com/catboost/catboost#8ae16dec)`

Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `/Users/name/Desktop/catboost-prediction-api/target/debug/build/catboost-sys-8842a384b00a8c82/build-script-build` (exit status: 101)
  --- stderr
  thread 'main' panicked at /Users/name/.cargo/git/checkouts/catboost-113273d315325944/8ae16de/catboost/rust-package/catboost-sys/build.rs:34:13:
  Failed to run build_native.py : Permission denied (os error 13)
  note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace

How can I install and run this package? Can someone help me here?
I am using a M2 Mac, if that is relevant information here

Looking at catboost-sys/build.rs:30-35, it appears that it tries to execute /Users/name/.cargo/git/checkouts/catboost-113273d315325944/8ae16de/build_native.py.  For that to work on macOS, the file must be executable and python3 must be a command that is in your $PATH.

If the file is not executable, then open an issue in the catboost GitHub repository.  If python3 is not a command in your $PATH, then you probably need to install it.

Both python and python3 are executable commands in path, yet it still throws the same error, I will create an issue in catboost

@AbinavR can u share link on issue?
